# Email Post View Count to Author Weekly

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi Guys I am very new to wordpress and am learning, the following code result, is something, I tried and have edited my question afterwards,

```
include('wp-load.php');
// FOR GET_USERDATA FUNCTION & $WPDB
include('wp-includes/pluggable.php');
```

//  include ('wp-includes/author-template.php');

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);

require('./wp-blog-header.php');
require_once ('wp-content/themes/directoryengine/includes/places.php');

//    $count = convert_place($post_ID);
```

?>

```
<?php
        function sendMail() {
            $authors=get_users();

            $i=0;
            //get all users list
            foreach($authors as $author){                   
                $authorList[$i]['id']=$author->data->ID;
                $authorList[$i]['name']=$author->data->display_name;
                $authorList[$i]['user_email']=$author->data->user_email;
                $i++;
            }

            $to = array();
            foreach($authorList as $author){
                $args=array(
                    'post_type'=> 'place',
                    'author'=>$author['id']
        //            'caller_get_posts'=>1
                );

                $email = $author['user_email'];

                $query = new WP_Query($args);
                $count_key = 'view_count';
                //Returns values of the custom field with the specified key     from the specified post.
                $count = get_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, true);

                if($query->have_posts() ) {
                    echo $email.'<br>';
                    while($query->have_posts()){
                                $query->the_post();

                                $post_ID = get_the_ID();
                                $view_count = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'view_count', true );
                                //the_title();
                                if($view_count==null){
                                      $view_count = 0;
                                }

                                $pauthor = $author['name'];
                                $ptitle = get_the_title($post_ID);                                                                  
                                $from_email = "****@gmail.com";
                                $headers = "From:".$from_email;
                                $body = '';
                                $body.= 'Dear '. $author['name'].'\r\n';
                                $body.= 'This is to notify you of your place view count below: \r\n';
                                $body.= get_the_title($post_ID).' :<b> '.$view_count.'</b>\r\n' ;
                                $body.= 'From: Admin';


                                echo $body.'<br>';

                    }   
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                }



            }

            echo $body;


        }
        echo sendMail();

?>
```

I would like to send $body to each user, so if a users has multiple posts, they get sent in one email to their respective users..

Comment: Hi Mevius, I do understand the cron job part, thanks but would help a more detail advise, on this solution, pls....

Comment: You would need to create a script that does what you wish in this case `get post view and send to authors` then get that script to be run via a CRON job as @rnevius has said.

Comment: HI Eli Stone thanks for the advise, do you mind helping, with some code examples, as I am wordpress beginner?